# AgGrid: Need to wrap text inside pinned rows

Tags: javascript, css, height, ag-grid

Contraints:

- data comes from an API
- the text inside the pinned rows need to be wrapped (like we see in the actual non-pinned rows)
- content under the pinned/locked rows can scroll normally
- content can be multi-line or just plain long

in the MVCE example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-pinned-wrapped-row-being-hidden-n2p2pm?file=/main.js):

- the data comes via an API
- we can wrap the *content* (line #7-8 in main.js)
- we can put ... for overflowing text, but we don't want that (line #43 in main.js)
- we can't wrap the *content in the pinned row* (colored blue/red)
- we can set the height of the rows (line# 89-91 in main.js)

  - but, why we need to handle it ourselves?
  - also, change the width of the columns, and these "hard-coded-length" wouldn't auto-correct itself elegantly

[In the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-height/#height-for-pinned-rows) it says:

> it is not possible to dynamically change the height once set. However this is easily solved by just setting the pinned row data again which resets the row heights.

when/where to set this ☝️

Looking for configs which can make ALL the columns respect wrapping despite the length/font/styling of the actual content;

Looking for some help from agGrid pros... Thanks